# Define beginning time df pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am a beginner with pandas data handling, I have a python dataframe with events

[image]

I need to add a new column beside time and define `t`, with t=0 for 625.68 and increment it everytime the `time` column is increasing. Example, for 626.69 the column `t` must contains 1.01

How can I define that rule with python pandas ?

Thank you

Comment: `df['t'] = df['time'] - 625.68`  or `df['t'] = df['time'] - df['time'].min()`?

Comment: Or subtract  `df['Time'].min()`

Comment: Silly I am, so obvious. Thank you guys